# Embedded Jetty + ShiroFilter problems

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jetty, shiro, embedded-jetty

I haven't asked questions here yet, but after around 2 months of struggle on this, I decided to finally ask for help.

I am new to Java, this is actually my first project (just for fun), in which I am trying to create a web server with Jetty (without a web.xml descriptor) and Shiro authentication (with shiro.ini configuration file), but for some reason I cannot make it work. I tried pretty much everything I found on the internet, tried starting over, Read all The FMs... But nothing...

The final situation is that I get errors about no EnvironmentListener registered:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebEnvironment found: no EnvironmentLoaderListener registered?
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractFilter.init(AbstractFilter.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.initialize(FilterHolder.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:852)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:742)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:399)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at MyPackage.Main.main(Main.java:89)
```

So after a lot of reading, I ended up with this addition to the code:

```
EnvironmentLoaderListener listener = new EnvironmentLoaderListener();
secured.callContextInitialized(listener, new ServletContextEvent(secured.getServletContext()));
```

I also had a different error before, related to SecurityManager not set (or something), but for some reason, I don't get that error now?

To fix it, I used that code (it is commented now, as apparently I don't need it anymore, but anyways, at this point it makes no difference if it is commented or not...)

```
    //Factory<SecurityManager> factory=new IniSecurityManagerFactory("src/main/resources/shiro.ini");
    //SecurityManager securityManager=factory.getInstance();
    //SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager(securityManager);
```

So after all, I ended up with this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$Context.log(ContextHandler.java:2059)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoader.initEnvironment(EnvironmentLoader.java:127)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener.contextInitialized(EnvironmentLoaderListener.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:801)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:499)
    at MyPackage.Main.main(Main.java:72)
```

This is my code, I guess it has much to optimize, but as I am a newbie to Java, I am open to any suggestions...

```
import java.util.EnumSet;
import javax.servlet.DispatcherType;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;
import org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener;
import org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Initializing server...");
        PropertyConfigurator.configure("config//log4j.properties");

        final ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);

        context.setContextPath("/");
        context.setResourceBase("src/main/webapp/main");
        context.setClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());

        context.addServlet(DefaultServlet.class, "/*");

        context.addServlet("MyPackage.CheckLogin", "/checklogin");

        final ServletHolder jsp = context.addServlet(JspServlet.class, "*.jsp");
        jsp.setInitParameter("classpath", context.getClassPath());

        final ServletContextHandler secured = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);

        secured.setContextPath("/protected");
        secured.setResourceBase("src/main/webapp/protected");
        secured.setClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());

        secured.addServlet(DefaultServlet.class, "/*");

        final ServletHolder jsp2 = secured.addServlet(JspServlet.class, "*.jsp");
        jsp2.setInitParameter("classpath", context.getClassPath());

        EnvironmentLoaderListener listener = new EnvironmentLoaderListener();
        secured.callContextInitialized(listener, new ServletContextEvent(secured.getServletContext()));  

        //Factory<SecurityManager> factory=new IniSecurityManagerFactory("src/main/resources/shiro.ini");
        //SecurityManager securityManager=factory.getInstance();
        //SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager(securityManager);

        secured.addFilter(ShiroFilter.class,"/protected/*",EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST,DispatcherType.FORWARD,DispatcherType.INCLUDE,DispatcherType.ERROR));

        HandlerCollection hc = new HandlerCollection();
        hc.addHandler(secured);
        hc.addHandler(context);

        final Server server = new Server(8080);     
        server.setHandler(hc);

        System.out.println("Starting server...");
        try {
            server.start();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to start server!");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Server running...");
        while(true) {
            try {
                server.join();
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Server interrupted!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I pretty much tried everything I could figure out, so please help me fix it, as it is now driving me crazy...

If any additional information is needed, please let me know and I will provide it :)

edit: I tried to go through all the listed classes in the stack trace, but after a few hours spent in reading the different java classes and functions in them, I got into a dead end...

Jetty jar version: jetty-all-9.3.0-M2

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question, but I recently ran into a similar issue. Working off of your code, I ended up changing the way you are creating the EnvironmentLoaderListener from:

```
EnvironmentLoaderListener listener = new EnvironmentLoaderListener();
secured.callContextInitialized(listener, new ServletContextEvent(secured.getServletContext())); 

secured.addFilter(ShiroFilter.class,"/protected/*",EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST,DispatcherType.FORWARD,DispatcherType.INCLUDE,DispatcherType.ERROR));
```

to:

```
//Setup the environment loader listener to initialize Shiro and indicate where our ini file is
servletContextHandler.setInitParameter("shiroConfigLocations", "classpath:shiro.ini");
secured.addEventListener(new EnvironmentLoaderListener());

//Create and init the Shiro filter that will lookup and use environment we just created     
secured.addFilter(
        "org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.IniShiroFilter", "/*", EnumSet.of(
                DispatcherType.INCLUDE, DispatcherType.REQUEST,
                DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.ERROR));
```

Hope this helps!